# Reverse a string by words using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

my program below reverses a string, not by char but by word.

**Sample Input** Hello Mello
**Sanple Output** Hello Mello Hello

I don't know where I'm getting the first Hello from.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char input[255];
  char *head; // head of a word.
  char *tail; // tail of a word.

  printf("Enter a sentence: ");
  gets_s(input); // read a whole line.
  tail = input + strlen(input) - 1;

  while (tail >= input) 
    {
      if (*tail == 0 || *tail == ' ') 
        {
          tail--; // move to the tail of a word.
        }
      else 
        {
          tail[1] = 0;
          head = tail;
          while (head >= input) 
            {
              if (head == input || *(head - 1) == ' ') 
                {
                  printf("%s",input); // output a word.
                  printf(" ");

                  tail = head - 1; // seek the next word.
                  break;
                }
              head--; // move to the head of a word.
            }
        }
    }

  printf("\n\n");
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Could anyone be of any assistance?

Comment: Yeah it has to be quite C-ish C++ ... Not allowed use Strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean to printf head, not input. You're printing from the start of the string, not from the start of the word you just found.

```
printf("%s",head); // output a word.
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly, now my mind can be at ease :)
(I'll mark it correct after timer)

Comment: I understand now why it was printing the word it just found.